# Iterate over an array of hashes in puppet

Tags: arrays, hash, puppet

I have hiera data in puppet as follows:

```
elasticsearch::cluster_name: 'elasticsearch-dev'
elasticsearch::masterlist: [ "elasticsearchdev01.domain.com", "elasticsearchdev02.domain.com", "elasticsearchdev03.domain.com" ]
elasticsearch::kibanalist: [ "kibanadev01.domain.com" ]
```

And my manifest contains this:

```
  $masterlist = hiera('elasticsearch::masterlist')
  $kibanalist = hiera('elasticsearch::kibanalist')

  if ( $::fqdn in $masterlist ) or ( $::fqdn in $kibanalist ) {
    $cluster_name = hiera('elasticsearch::cluster_name')
  }

  else {
    notify { 'No cluster for node':
      message => "${::fqdn} is not configured to be in any cluster in the hiera data",
    }
  }
```

I would like to modify this to allow multiple clusters to be configured for a single environment, and I'm not sure of the best way to implement this. I want to be able to group the master lists with their corresponding cluster names, and then call the relevant cluster name for each node.

I think perhaps I need to use an array of hashes and iterate over it, but I don't know how to cover this in my manifest.

Comment: I wonder if the [Puppet docs on iteration](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_iteration.html) help at all?  You may need a recent Puppet for this to work.

Comment: I will point you at documentation since this is a theoretical question: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_iteration.html. If you make the question specific, then we can give you a specific answer. That documentation will be a push in the right direction for now though.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to restructure your data as a Hash of Hashes:

```
elasticsearch::clusters:
  'elasticsearch-dev':
    masterlist: [ "elasticsearchdev01.domain.com", "elasticsearchdev02.domain.com", "elasticsearchdev03.domain.com" ]
    kibanalist: [ "kibanadev01.domain.com" ]
```

And then have in your manifests:

```
$clusters = hiera('elasticsearch::clusters')

$mycluster = $clusters.filter |$cluster, $data| {
  ($::fqdn in $data['masterlist']) or ($::fqdn in $data['kibanalist'])
}

if ($mycluster.empty) {
  notify { 'No cluster for node':
    message => "${::fqdn} is not configured to be in any cluster in the hiera data",
  }
}

$cluster_name = $mycluster.keys[0]
notice($cluster_name)
```

You might want to also consider replacing the deprecated `hiera()` call with `lookup()` and using `$facts['networking']['fqdn']` instead of the legacy `$::fqdn`.

Comment: This gave me a great place to start. After implementing this I think that what I actually want to do is write a function that will search all the master/kibana lists in the hiera data (given multiple clusters configured) for the fqdn of the node. If it is not there it will send a notify, and if it is then it will return the corresponding cluster name, masterlist and kibanalist. I can see that I can search the lists from what you have suggested above, but I then don't seem to be able to use any variables set outside of the iteration.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was thinking you just didn't know how to structure the data. It actually can be done. Let me refactor.

Comment: @clp, I think this is what you meant?